# Onmouseout event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html:

```
<div class="baloon_signup"  onmouseover="pinkImg(this)" onmouseout="whiteImg(this)">
    <img src="images/prijavi.png" class="imageResponsive" />
</div>
```

and this javascript functions:

```
<script>
function pinkImg(x) 
    {
    x.innerHTML = '<img src="images/prijaviH.png" class="imageResponsive" />';
    }

function whiteImg(x) 
    {
    x.innerHTML = '<img src="images/prijavi.png" class="imageResponsive" />';
    }
</script>
```

Function pinkImg which is triggered on onmouseover event is working properly, but whiteImg which is triggered on onmouseout event is not working at all. I have checked image paths and they are correct. When I hover with mouse on div, image changes, but when I go out with mouse image stays the same.

Thank you in advance

Comment: try an alert() inside whiteImg and see if it works

Comment: Tested you code. No problems here. Any errors in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the innerHTML of the div, just change the src of the image element itself.

Maybe your div is larger than the image which causing your onmouseout event don't get fired. With your example code, the div has a default width of 100%.

Try this example code including jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="baloon_signup"  onmouseover="pinkImg()" onmouseout="whiteImg()">
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/5/4/b/11949892282132520602led_circle_green.svg.thumb.png" class="imageResponsive" />
</div>

<script>
function pinkImg() {
    $('.imageResponsive').attr('src', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/5/7/b/5/1194989231691813435led_circle_red.svg.thumb.png');
}

function whiteImg() {
    $('.imageResponsive').attr('src', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/5/4/b/11949892282132520602led_circle_green.svg.thumb.png');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use div id.

```
<div id="x" class="baloon_signup"  onmouseover="pinkImg(x)" onmouseout="whiteImg(x)">
    <img src="images/prijavi.png" class="imageResponsive" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You have solutions with jQUery: http://jsfiddle.net/vgmppkdg/1/ and .hover(whatIn,whatOut) function

HTML:

```
<div id="baloon_signup">
 <img src="images/prijavi.png" class="imageResponsive" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $baloon = $('#baloon_signup')

$baloon.hover(function(){
    $baloon.html('x<img src="images/prijaviH.png" class="imageResponsive" />');
}, function(){
    $baloon.html('y<img src="images/prijavi.png" class="imageResponsive" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below JavaScript code. (Not used jQuery)

```
<div class="baloon_signup" onmouseover="pinkImg()" onmouseout="whiteImg()" >
<img id="animate" src="https://www.gstatic.com/android/market_images/web/play_logo_x2.png" class="imageResponsive" />
```

```
function pinkImg(){
 //alert('onmouseover');
    document.getElementById("animate").src = "https://www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png";
}
function whiteImg(){
 //alert('onmouseout');
    document.getElementById("animate").src = "https://www.gstatic.com/android/market_images/web/play_logo.png";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ovkyqqdo/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title></title>
    <script>
        function pinkImg(x) {
            x.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/originals/2013/Photoshop_Image_of_the_horse_053857_.jpg" class="imageResponsive" style="height:300px;width:300px" />';
            return false;
        }

        function whiteImg(x) {
            x.innerHTML = '<img src="http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg" class="imageResponsive" style="height:300px;width:300px" />';
            return false;
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="baloon_signup"  onmouseover="pinkImg(this);" onmouseout="whiteImg(this);">
    <img src="images/prijavi.png" class="imageResponsive" />
</div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```